# Calling a web Method that returns a non String by AJAX [ASP.net]

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asmx, microsoft-ajax

i made a web function in the C# file called `test` it returns a simple List for testing

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
public static List<string> test()
{
    List<string> a = new List <string>() ; 
    a.Add("1s");
    a.Add("2s");
    return a; 
}
```

i tried to call this `WEBMETHOD` from the front end using JQUERY AJAX

```
     function Test() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/test",
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    x = msg;
                    $(".resultbox").html(msg.d);
                }
            });

            return x;

}
```

when i call test() ; from the console  the message was :

```
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8   jquery-1.6.1.min.js:18
```

in common cases i convert objects into JSON and return them and this usually work but i'm interested to know how objects are returned from the WEBMETHOD  to the front end are they  serialized into text , why did this error happened .

Comment: no point in returning x. x will most probably be null as the it fires before the callback.

Comment: not right , i've defined  x as a global variable , also not the scope of the answer

Comment: lets argue later on callback methods and global scope and why return a globally scoped variable later. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
function Test() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/test",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            msg = msg.hasOwnProperty("d") ? msg.d : msg;
            $.each(msg, function (index, value) {
                $(".resultbox").append("<p>" + value + "</p>");
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: actually u didn't get what the Question Says , i don't have problem in calling web methods in from Jquery , i had another Inquery

Comment: @HadyElsahar: i believe your problem will be solved when you understand that you are just starting to learn javascript. trust us. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that DOM exception is related to passing an array object into `innerHTML()`, via jQuery's `html()` method. Try formatting your array values as a string first instead:

```
success: function (msg) {
  // Builds a string like '1s, 2s'
  var formattedMessage = msg.d.join(', ');

  $(".resultbox").html(formattedMessage);
}
```

Manually building the formatted string is no fun, of course. To improve that situation, look into client-side templating solutions like jQuery Templates and its successor JsRender.

Comment: from ur answer ,i see that the WEBMETHOD returns the LIST<string> to the front end a JSarray , is that true ?  what about the other objects   ? that was the core of the Question

Comment: Any collection like a List<T> or Array will become a JavaScript array. Objects will become JavaScript key/value pairs. Scalar values will map to their corresponding JavaScript type.

Answer (score -2):

Since you are sending a list of string from the `WebMethod` so `msg` will be an array. In that case `msg.d` will give you `undefined` result. If you want to show them as a combined string seperated by comma then try this.

`ajax` is async in nature by default you cannot return the ajax response from `Test` method. If you want to return it then set `async` to `false` which will wait until the response comes and then you can return it.

```
function Test() {
            var x = null;//Define variable x
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "webservice.asmx/test",//Web service url
                data: "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    x = msg;
                    $(".resultbox").html(msg.join(','));
                }
            });

            return x;
}
```

Comment: its perfectly valid. its a page method! http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: page methods are a valid tocall from the front end , actually it's designed to be so . however this is not the issue i've posted in the Question

Comment: oh shankar. i didn't read your answer at all. this deserves a -1. please spare some time and read this http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx

Comment: @naveen - Why does it deserve -1? And how does the link you provided links to my answer or OP's question.

Comment: `.d` is bound to be there. thats why and hey did you -1 my answer? any valid reasons?

Comment: Looking at the `WebMethod`'s code how can you say `.d` is bound to be there? It is is returning a List<string> which gets converted to JavaScript array. `msg` is an array. Understand the question and answer before downvoting!